# Android EditText box and cursor/text moving around

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an android application that has 3 **EditText** widgets. When I enter values, everything is fine. When I click a button, the cursor and/or text like falls below the line as shown in the images. I can click and drag the text/cursor up and down (like it was a date chooser or something). This does happen on all 3 fields. This happens on a device, and in an emulator.

I do not recall changing any properties on those widgets that could cause this, and such, examining all the properties does not shed any light on what would cause it. Even if there are not any values, such as the the **discount** field, I can move the **hint** text just like I can move the user entered values. I thought perhaps it had something to do what I was doing with onClickListenener, but I do not change anything there. I can choose a selection from the overflow menu and it happens there too. Any ideas on why this is happening?

The XML for the field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_calc">

 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etxtPrice"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:hint="Price"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etxtDiscount"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:hint="Discount" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="%"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etxtTax"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:hint="Tax" />

    </TableRow>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the height of the edittext is wrap_content.. the edit text can accommodate any number of lines of text. Use android:singleLine="true" attribute to force it to single line.

Comment: Adding this line does not change the undesired behavior.